# SQL update failing - inputs with "read-only" attr

Tags: php, sql, forms

Sorry. Simple copy/paste error. No programming issues.

I have a form with action pointing to `PHP file` which is doing `SQL UPDATE`.
As my form have some `read only` input field - (not to be changed).

My problem is that the form has some field - which being POST and PHP is NOT EXPECTING those, basically they never got used.

When I submit all of the field my SQL query is failing (no update is taking place). Why?

How can  tell the form not to POST some of the field. Only read/write field (those without readonly="readonly")?

How to tell PHP to not include all of the values that has been received from the form?

Should I include in the update read-only field (update will not take place as there is no change to those fields.)?

Any suggestion much appreciated.

Please note:

- when no "readonly" used everything is working fine

**UPDATE**

My form PHP (HTML result lower):

```
<form action="update-news.php?updateID='.$id.'" class="form note-form" style="display: block;" method="post">
    <label>ID</label>
    <input name="id" type="text" value="'.$id.'" readonly="readonly" />
    <br class="clr">

    <label>Create by</label>
    <input name="id" type="text" value="'.$usr.'" readonly="readonly" />
    <br class="clr">

    <label>Updated by</label>
    <input name="id" type="text" value="'.$never_update_user.'" readonly="readonly" />
    <br class="clr">

    <label>Created</label>
    <input name="id" type="text" value="'.$created.'" readonly="readonly" />
    <br class="clr">

    <label>Last Update</label>
    <input name="id" type="text" value="'.$never_update.'" readonly="readonly" />
    <br class="clr">
    <br /><br />

    <label>Live</label>
    <input name="live" type="checkbox" ',($live ? 'checked="checked"':''),'/>
    <br class="clr">

    <label>Title</label>
    <input name="title" type="text" value="'.$title.'" />
    <br class="clr">

    <label>Content</label>
    <textarea id="content" name="content" type="text" rows="5" cols="75">'.$content.'</textarea>
    <br class="clr">

    <input type="submit" class="button" value="Update" id="submit" />
</form>
```

Form HTML:

```
<form method="post" style="display: block;" class="form note-form" action="update-news.php?updateID=6">
                            <label>ID</label>
                            <input type="text" readonly="readonly" value="6" name="id">
                            <br class="clr">

                            <label>Create by</label>
                            <input type="text" readonly="readonly" value="user@gmail.com" name="id">
                            <br class="clr">

                            <label>Updated by</label>
                            <input type="text" readonly="readonly" value="user@gmail.com" name="id">
                            <br class="clr">

                            <label>Created</label>
                            <input type="text" readonly="readonly" value="August 15, 2011, 2:24 pm" name="id">
                            <br class="clr">

                            <label>Last Update</label>
                            <input type="text" readonly="readonly" value="August 15, 2011, 2:25 pm" name="id">
                            <br class="clr">
                            <br><br>

                            <label>Live</label>
                            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="live">
                            <br class="clr">

                            <label>Title</label>
                            <input type="text" value="How to compare two dates in php and echo newer one?" name="title">
                            <br class="clr">

                            <label>Content</label>
                            <textarea cols="75" rows="5" type="text" name="content" id="content">123</textarea>



                            <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Update" class="button">
                    </form>
```

`UPDATE-NEWS.php`:

```
<?php

session_name('users');
session_set_cookie_params(2*7*24*60*60);
session_start();

define('INCLUDE_CHECK',true);

require 'connect.php';
require 'functions.php';

if(!$_SESSION['id']) {
    header ("Location: index.php"); 
}


        //Function to sanitize values received from the form. Prevents SQL injection
        function clean($str) {
            $str = @trim($str);
            if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
                $str = stripslashes($str);
            }
            return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
        }

        //Sanitize the POST values
        $id = clean($_POST['id']);
        $usr2 = $_SESSION['usr'];
        $live = (isset($_POST['live']))?1:0;
        $updated = date("F j, Y, g:i a",time()+60*60);
        $title= clean($_POST['title']);
        $content = clean($_POST['content']);

        //Create INSERT query
        $qry = "UPDATE news SET usr2 = '$usr2', live = '$live', updated = '$updated', title = '$title', content = '$content' WHERE id='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']). "'  ";
        $result = mysql_query($qry);
        echo mysql_error();

        //Check whether the query was successful or not
        if($result) {
            header("location: notes.php");
            exit();
        }else {
            die("Query failed");

        }
    ?>
```

Comment: Could you rephrase that please?  Do you mean that fields are being passed through your form and added to an SQL query, even though you don't want them to be added to the query?  If that's the case, you would need to filter the $_POST array for properties that meet a certain critera.  Post your code up and we can take a look.

Comment: Just... don't include them in the update query. Maybe show us how you're currently *including* them? Because that doesn't happen automagically.

Comment: You get to pick what is used in the query, so what is posted is immaterial. If the query is failing, it is probably malformed SQL. Post the code you are using to execute the query.

Comment: Not really understanding how submitting all fields in a form is causing your query to fail. When you submit a form, everything in the `<form></form>` tags get POSTed. The issue seems to be in your query. I would fix that rather than figure out how to not POST read only fields

Comment: There is one simple answer to this without changing much and not needing to understand more: using `disabled="disabled"` instead of `readonly="readonly"` will mean the browser does not send those fields in the submit. However, the better solution would be to understand how the submit/query works...

Comment: The whole UPDATE stuff, that is going on server side, depends only on server side script - PHP. You can tell it to ignore anything, rewrite any POST/GET data received, and do anything you want. If you encounter problems with SQL updates, I would suggest you add some `print_r($query)` inside PHP code, to see that query. If it is not doing update, then it may be SQL syntax problems, so please, post your PHP code, if you need more help.

Comment: @NullUserException - when I remove the `readonly` everything is working fine.

Comment: The first problem I see is you have multiple fields named id. Why is that?

Comment: If I were to guess, I'd say your query actually works fine regardless. But because you have a condition (`WHERE id=...`), this condition is incorrect some times and thus nothing gets updated. This funky behavior could be the result of having multiple fields with the same name (id).

Comment: @NullUserException - which lines?

Comment: Please fix your title (a list of technologies does not describe the problem), and fix the formatting of your code, too.

Comment: Your "ID," "Create by," "Update By" and others are all named id (`name = "id"`)

Comment: Bloody hell :/ Sorry guys. Copy-paste mistake.

Comment: @NullUserException - Works! Your have a good eye to details! Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly *a* problem is that you have several fields with `name="id"`. Only the last one of those will be POSTed to the server as `$_POST['id']`, which is very likely a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can simply set `disabled="disabled"` property of that field which you do not want to submit.